# Android deep link does not work if the app is already opened by deep link

Tags: android, deep-linking

Deep link doesn't work if it is opened by deep link already.
I've already read this one [Android deep link does not work if the app is opened by deep link already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931028/android-deep-link-does-not-work-if-the-app-is-opened-by-deep-link-already).
So I know if I add singleTask launchmode to LaunchActivity, it works.

But I wonder why it is only works, when I add singleTask launch mode to LaunchActivity.
Why isn't it works when I add standard launch mode to LaunchActivity?